# Get the id_user_app if not exists in id_user_rq

Tags: mysql, query, performance, query-performance

I'm building a application and have this table for users relationships. I need to build some queries like for example:

- Who invited me as a friend?
- Who I invited to be my friend?
- Who I accept as friend?

And need some help because for me are complex queries :(. Also I don't know if open trhead for each of the question or leave all them here in this topic, what's the best?

For the first question: I have this table structure: http://www.dropmocks.com/mBjNvF and need to get the id_user_app if not exists in id_user_rq as the title said. I try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*, p.*, u.email FROM default_relations_users A 
    LEFT JOIN default_relations_users B ON (A.id_user_rq = B.id_user_ap
    AND A.id_user_ap = B.id_user_rq AND A.id_user_rq = 1)
    LEFT JOIN default_users u ON (u.id = A.id_user_rq) 
    LEFT JOIN default_profiles p ON (p.user_id = A.id_user_rq)
    GROUP BY A.id_user_rq
```

But it's not working, any advice or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*, p.*, u.email FROM
              (SELECT * FROM default_relation_users WHERE id_user_rq = 1) A
              LEFT JOIN
              (SELECT * FROM default_relation_users WHERE id_user_ap = 1) B
              ON (A.id_user_rq=B.id_user_ap AND B.id_user_rq=A.id_user_ap)
              LEFT JOIN default_users u ON (u.id = A.id_user_rq) 
              LEFT JOIN default_profiles p ON (p.user_id = A.id_user_rq)
              WHERE B.id_user_ap IS NULL
              GROUP BY A.id_user_rq
```

I changed A and B to be subqueries using 1 for `id_user_rq` and `id_user_ap`

If you want the opposite, just reverse A and B subqueries to something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*, p.*, u.email FROM
              (SELECT * FROM default_relation_users WHERE id_user_ap = 1) A
              LEFT JOIN
              (SELECT * FROM default_relation_users WHERE id_user_rq = 1) B
              ON (A.id_user_rq=B.id_user_ap AND B.id_user_rq=A.id_user_ap)
              LEFT JOIN default_users u ON (u.id = A.id_user_rq) 
              LEFT JOIN default_profiles p ON (p.user_id = A.id_user_rq)
              WHERE B.id_user_rq IS NULL
              GROUP BY A.id_user_rq
```

Comment: Nop, doesn't work. Your last query returns id_user_rq=2 and isn't correct because exists at id_user_ap

Comment: "WHERE B.id_user_ap IS NULL" why this? I can't understand why you filter by B.id_user_ap IS NULL because this will never happen.

Comment: I suggested `WHERE IS NULL` because you have LEFT JOINs. The query behavior may change if you use INNER JOINs instead. Then, there is no need for `WHERE IS NULL`.

Comment: I tried with this query: SELECT DISTINCT A . * , p . * , u.email FROM default_relations_users A INNER JOIN default_relations_users B ON ( A.id_user_rq = B.id_user_ap AND A.id_user_ap = B.id_user_rq
AND A.id_user_rq =1 ) INNER JOIN default_users u ON ( u.id = A.id_user_rq ) INNER JOIN default_profiles p ON ( p.user_id = A.id_user_rq ) GROUP BY A.id_user_rq LIMIT 0 , 100 but this doesn't return any values. I'm wrong?

Comment: When you used LEFT JOIN, did any data come back ? If so, how many rows?

Comment: yes two rows are returned

Comment: How many rows are supposed to come back ?

Comment: two but the result for that query was 1,2 and 1,3 when should be 1,3 and 1,4 meaning "id_user_app if not exists in id_user_rq"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3667/discussion-between-rolandomysqldba-and-reynierpm)